# Recommend A Dual WAN Router, W/ Support For More Than 255 LAN Hosts

Tags: router

Looking for a router/firewall model with the following specifications:

```
Dual WAN (Failover mode)
SPI Firewall
Support for at least 100mbps of throughput
Support for more than 256hosts on the LAN
```

Most routers I am finding, only support a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0 (255 hosts) on the LAN.

VPN not important. Unified thread management (AntiVirus, Spyware, Etc) not important.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On a budget? [DrayTek](http://www.draytek.co.uk/products/comparison.html) fits the bill.

Comment: Actually there does seem to be a 90mbps limit on WAN throughput, but you get what you pay for :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not on a short term budget and you are looking for a device with more investment protection that will scale with your company <end of sales rant/>

Cisco 892 would do that fine, dual WAN interfaces and you can use whatever subnet size you want on the LAN side. Only 50Mbit throughput though.
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps10203/index.html

Cisco 2911 will do the same but with 180Mbit throughput (and supports loads of other features).
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps10540/index.html